# Why can I not assign exec permissions to a file on the SD card?

Tags: sd-card, file-system, file-permissions

```
shell@android:/sdcard/SW # ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw      128 2012-09-22 11:42 usb0config.sh
shell@android:/sdcard/SW # chmod 777 usb0config.sh                             
shell@android:/sdcard/SW # ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw      128 2012-09-22 11:42 usb0config.sh
shell@android:/sdcard/SW #
```

Why can I not assign exec permissions to a file on the SD card?

```
$ adb shell su -c mount |grep -si sdcard
/dev/block/vold/179:97 /mnt/ext_sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/ext_sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/sdcard fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0


$ adb shell su -c "mount -t vfat -o umask=0000 /dev/fuse /mnt/sdcard"
mount: Block device required
```

Now it seems remount successfully.

```
$ adb shell su -c "mount -t vfat -o remount,umask=0000 /dev/fuse /mnt/sdcard"
```

but the file yet cannot be assigned 777 mode.

```
shell@android:/sdcard/Sw # ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw      128 2012-09-22 11:42 usb0config.sh
shell@android:/sdcard/Sw # chmod 777 usb0config.sh                             
shell@android:/sdcard/Sw # ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw      128 2012-09-22 11:42 usb0config.sh
```

The mount info doesn't change comparing to before remount's.

```
$ adb shell su -c mount |grep -si sdcard
/dev/block/vold/179:97 /mnt/ext_sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/ext_sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/sdcard fuse rw,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you've done something unusual with your device, the SD card will be formatted as a FAT file system, which does not support *nix file permissions. [This Linux FAQ](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/linuxfaq/index.html#2) entry from one of MIT's professors explains it a bit, and also explains how you can potentially use mount options to change the permission mode of the device (this would require root, though, and affect all files/folders on the device). Also, the SD card in Android is mounted by default with the `-noexec` flag.

For the exec bit you'd probably want to remount with a umask of `0000`, since the umask is essentially a binary NOT of the permissions you want (so umask `0000` says **don't** mask out any permissions, allow them all). Untested, but doing it temporarily would be something along the lines of:

```
mount -t vfat -o umask=0000 /dev/your/sdcard/device /mnt/sdcard
```

The mount point may need to be changed from `/mnt/sdcard` to something slightly different depending on your device. Again, though, I believe `mount` requires that you have root permissions for this.

Comment: I try remount using your gave command, but failed, please see supplement of my question.

Comment: please see my question's update.

Comment: @VictorS: It looks like you have both an internal and an external SD card. The internal one is not treated the same way, and I don't know if there's a way to get it re-mounted with the permissions you want. Alternatively, though, you could execute your script by invoking sh: `sh usb0config.sh`.